# How to put all DDLs and scripts for stored procedures into TFS for SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008 provides a solution explore. I have an existing database with many stored procedures, triggers, functions, views.

So I want to all those scripts and DDL can be maintained like .NET codes with Visual Studio connect to TFS.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2010, you can create a Database project, import the DDL from your database into the project, then commit to source control like any other project.

Comment: Thank you. Have tried and it works fine. But I want to the project in SSMS like MyDB Scripts.ssmssqlproj. Try it in ssms, but there is no import function like VS2010. VS2020 solution can not be opened by ssms. Anyway to share it between?

Comment: None that I know of, sorry.  It may exist, but I'm not aware of it.